# How to run 2 versions of app on the same device without overriding the previous version?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, versioning

I currently have an app I created in xcode running on a device.  Unfortunately something happened to the project files and I had to recreate a lot of them.  I would like to run the the project I just recreated on the same device WITHOUT deleting or overriding the previous app made from the same project. Is this possible, and if so how to do it?

Comment: You need to change the bundle ID to be able to install the app as a different one besides the already installed other version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the bundle identifier of the other version to be able to install the 2 versions as it's the key thing behind app override